# Finding objects by class type using reflection for instantiating a Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm trying to make a "find by type" research into my database application.
In particular, I have a hierarchy of classes of type: Mother <-- Child1, Child2.
I have 3 corresponding repositories, i.e. classes annotated @Repository and extending PagingAndSortingRepository.

Now, I have a controller that needs to load all instances of type Child1 (or Child2) in the database.

That's my proposal for the method in the class ControllerClassForTheSearch:

```
public List<? extends Mother> findMotherByType(Class classToSearch)
        throws FindException {

    PagingAndSortingRepository<? extends Mother, Long> repo;
    try {
        repo = beanFactory.createBean(classToSearch);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FindException (this
                .getClass().getName(), classRepository);
    }

    return repo.findAll();
}
```

The beanFactory variable is defined as follow in the same class:

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClassForTheSearch implements BeanFactoryAware {
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(final BeanFactory beanFactory)
        throws BeansException {
       this.beanFactory = (AutowireCapableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
    }
    [...] // rest of the class code
```

However, it doesn't work: my repositories are interfaces, so they cannot be created (that's the error I get).
In other classes, repositories are autowired variables and they work fine, including the ones for Mother, Child1 and Child2.

Do you have any ideas how I can get to my result of finding classes of type Child1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced createBean with getBean and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna have a look at the [`Repositories`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/support/Repositories.html) helper class in Spring Data Commons. you can create one from a `ListableBeanFactory` and then get access to the repositories by managed domain type.